# After update to SDK 31 Room Database stopped working: COuld Not find @Entity which causes Room to not Build

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

[image: More info on the error][image: Build Error for Project]

This is what I'm seeing when I try to build my project. I haven't changed anything except what Android forced me to in the Manifest and I don't know where to go after this.

**Dao**

```
@Dao
interface SubscriberDAO {
@Insert
suspend fun insertSubscriber(subscriber: Subscriber): Long

@Update
suspend fun updateSubscriber(subscriber: Subscriber): Int

@Delete
suspend fun deleteSubscriber(subscriber: Subscriber): Int

@Query("DELETE FROM subscriber_data_table")
suspend fun deleteAll(): Int

@Query("SELECT * FROM subscriber_data_table")
fun getAllSubscribers(): LiveData<List<Subscriber>>

}
```

What is wrong?
I tried to change the `TargetSdk` back to 30 and it still didn't work

**Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.homeofficeprojects.samplearchitecturedatabasecoroutinesproject"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures{
        dataBinding = true
        // for view binding :
        // viewBinding = true
    }
    /*dataBinding{
        enabled = true
    }*/
}

dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.4.0"
    def room_version = "2.3.0"

    kotlin {
        experimental {
            coroutines "enable"
        }
    }

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // Annotation processor

    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
    // To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")



    //coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.0'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
}
```

**Subscriber**

```
package com.homeofficeprojects.samplearchitecturedatabasecoroutinesproject

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "subscriber_data_table")
data class Subscriber(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "subscriber_id")
    var id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "subscriber_name")
    var name: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "subscriber_email")
    var email: String
) {
    //constructor(): this(0, "", "")
}
```

Edit: I've added the Gradle Build file and Subscriber
kotlin class
Edit 2: Second picture, more info on the errors

Comment: Change targetSDK in the build gradle from 31 to use the SDK you had previously (don't change any thing else in the build gradle). If the issue still happens then odds on it's the other build gradle  changes. If so edit your question to include the build gradle. If it compiles with change to targetSDK, the you will need to edit your question to include the build gradle and the Subscriber class (Entity).

Comment: I tried SDK 30, it didn't change anything it seems. The weird thing about this is, i have several projects that use Room database, and they all worked until this recent update. I'm so confused. Maybe a new migration changed something?

Comment: try to delete | kotlin {
        experimental {
            coroutines "enable"
        }
    }

Comment: Looks like a `converters` issue while saving to column.

Comment: Try clean build / rebuild

Comment: It's none of those unfortunately. I don't really know where to go after this. I would check a previous project for verification, but this is the project I would use and it used to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up asking on reddit and was told to roll back the gradle dependency.
`classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"`
from
`ext.kotlin_version = "1.6.0"`
to
`ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.31"`
I'm not sure I would call that a way forward, but I can move on with my project so I'm calling it one until an actual answer comes through